# Dependency Injection in Swift, Not Data

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection

i have a question about Dependency Injection.

i read this post(https://medium.com/better-programming/modern-dependency-injection-in-swift-952286b308be)

the writer said that "Inject Services, Not Data"

in his example, UserDetailsViewController has its viewmodel(UserDetailsViewModel) and User Data(var user: User?)

but, maybe i think that the viewmodel may need an User.

like this

ex>

```
class UserDetailsViewModel {
    let user: User
    let service: NetworkModule
    init(user: User, service: NetworkModule) {
        self.user = user
        self.service = service
    }

    func requestUserDetail() {
        service.req(user.id)
    }
}
```

so is Injecting data wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the article describes it

> One of the first things to get straight is that dependency injection’s sole concern lies in constructing the service graph. To put that into English, it means the dependency-injection system creates and connects the services and objects that manage the application’s data.

First, let's clear out what's `DI` is I recommend this [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/what-is-dependency-injection-b2671b1ea90a).

Considering we already know what it is, injecting services in this article is basically saying injecting a manager object that manipulates the data instead of injecting the data itself, lets talk code.

Check the following example of `DI`.

```
struct DataModel {
    // dummy data
}
class Foo  {
    var dataModel: DataModel
    init(dataModel: DataModel){
        self.dataModel = dataModel
    }
}
```

That's a basic dependency injection example where you inject data, can call it data injection.

So it's all after all an injection regard of what it is, could be

- Service
- UI
- Data
  etc..

So for this article, he is trying to explain the differences and use cases between them, now for service injection simplified example.

```
struct DataModel {
    // dummy data
}
class ModelManager { // service class
    func getModel(dataModel: DataModel) -> DataModel{ // service
    return dataModel
    }
}
class Foo  {
    var dataModelManager: ModelManager
    var dataModel: DataModel
    init(dataModelManager: ModelManager, dataModel: DataModel){
        self.dataModelManager = dataModelManager
        self.dataModel = dataModel
        var proccessedData = dataModelManager.getModel(dataModel: dataModel) // service injection
    }
}
```

There is no big difference here, but that's what we call service injection.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ultra-light dependency injection container. [DIContainer](https://github.com/Tavernari/DIContainer)

It's cool because you can resolve the dependencies using `@Injected` before the properties, or if you prefer, you can call the method `resolve`.

For example:

```
let githubService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.githubService)
let gitlabService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.by(type: FetchService.self, withKey: "gitlab"))
let externalService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.by(type: ExternalSingletonService.self))
```

or

```
@Injected(.githubService)
var githubService: FetchService

@Injected(.by(type: FetchService.self, withKey: "gitlab"))
var gitlabService: FetchService

@InjectedSafe
var externalService: ExternalSingletonService?
```

With this, you can easily inject your models and services on your `ViewModels` or your `ViewControllers`.

I hope to help you with this lib.